# Grep everything within curly braces in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I got a file (Note: it's not a json file) that I need to parse and insert into a DB, so the rows starting with #TRANS within curly braces should belong to the row starting with #VER above. I guess I should use preg_match or preg_match_all but not sure how the regex should be?

```
#VER 1 5 20170128
{
   #TRANS 8000 {} 4016.00 20170128 "something"
   #TRANS 1100 {} -4016.00 20170128 "something"
}
#VER 1 6 20170128
{
   #TRANS 8010 {} 5016.00 20170128 "something else"
   #TRANS 1130 {} -5016.00 20170128 "something else"
}
```

I would split them up in two tables and I can do it in multiple step and not in one go. So first I would insert the VER row and then get the TRANS rows just below within curly braces and loop over the rows found and parse them.

Below is an example of how the DB will look like from the first example of the file:

```
Table VER:
ID | VER_DATE | (some other stuff)
5  | 20170128 | ...

Table TRANS:
ID | VER_ID | SERIAL | VALUE |   DATE
1  |    5   |  8000  |  4016 | 20170128
1  |    5   |  1100  | -4016 | 20170128
```

Comment: What is the DB architecture, exactly?

Comment: please show us an example of your expected row

Comment: Don't over-complicate things by trying to cram it all into one single expression, would be my suggestion ... Start by writing one rather simple expression, that breaks this apart into its, in this case two, components - `#VER ... { ... }`, and then loop over those and take it from there ...

Comment: Updated the post. Of course, I won't be able to do it in one go and it's completely fine to run it in multiple steps :) Not sure how to get the rows within brackets for each #VER row though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use Regex, something like this would do:

```
preg_match_all('/#VER (.*)\s*\{((\s*#TRANS\s*[0-9]+\s\{.*\}.*$)*\s*)\}/msU', $text, $matches);

$size = sizeof($matches[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    $text = $matches[2][$i];
    echo "================\n";
    echo $matches[1][$i]."\n";
    preg_match_all('/\s*#TRANS\s([0-9]+)\s(\{.*\})\s([0-9\-\.]+)\s([0-9]+)\s"(.*)"$/', $text, $matches2);
    $size2 = sizeof($matches2[0]); 
    for($j = 0; $j < $size2; $j++){
        echo $matches2[1][$j]."\n";
        echo $matches2[2][$j]."\n";
        echo $matches2[3][$j]."\n";
        echo $matches2[4][$j]."\n";
        echo $matches2[5][$j]."\n";
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
================
1 5 20170128
1100
{}
-4016.00
20170128
something
================
1 6 20170128
1130
{}
-5016.00
20170128
something else
```

You can split the headline `($matches[1][$i])` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't need to support a complex syntax and it's a one time conversion only you can do it very easily with `fopen` and `fgets`:

```php
<?php

$fp = fopen('/path/to/file', 'rb');

$head        = '';
$blockBuffer = '';

while (true) {
    $line = fgets($fp);

    if ($line === false) break;

    if (substr($line, 0, 4) === '#VER') {
        $head        = $line;
        $blockBuffer = '';
    }

    if (!empty($head)) {
        $blockBuffer .= $line;
    }

    if (trim($line) === '}') {
        var_dump($head);
        var_dump($blockBuffer);

        $head = '';
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a **brittle** way of parsing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a sort of compiler approach by parsing and processing each line. It has some ability to handle badly formatted data.

```
class ParserException extends Exception {
    public $line;
    function __construct($message, $line) {
        parent::__construct($message);
        $this->line = $line;
    }
}

class Parser {

    const Top = 1;
    const InBlock = 2;
    const Ver = 4;
    const Noop = 6;

    public $ver = null;

    function parse($input) {
        $lines = explode("\n", $input);
        $state = self::Top;
        $this->line = 1;
        try {
            foreach($lines as $line) {

                // echo "$line\n";
                switch($state) {
                    case self::Top:
                        if ( preg_match('/^#VER (\d) (\d) ([0-9]+)/', $line, $matches) ) {
                            $this->emitVer($matches);
                            $state = self::Ver;
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new ParserException("VER not found", $this->line);
                        }
                        break;
                    case self::Ver:
                        if ( substr(trim($line), 0, 1) == '{' ) {
                            $state = self::InBlock;
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new ParserException("Expected { ", $this->line);
                        }
                        break;
                    case self::InBlock:
                        $trimline = trim($line);
                        // echo ">>> $trimline\n";
                        // #TRANS 8000 {} 4016.00 20170128 "something"
                        if ( preg_match('/^#TRANS ([0-9]+) \{\} ([0-9.-]+) ([0-9]+) "(.*)"/', $trimline, $matches) ) {
                            $this->emitTrans($matches);
                        } elseif ( substr($trimline, 0, 1) == '}' ) {
                            $state = self::Top;
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new ParserException("Expected TRANS or } ", $this->line);
                        }                        
                        break;
                    default:
                        // unknown state
                        throw new ParserException("Unexpected error ", $this->line);                        
                        break;
                }
                $this->line++;
            }
        }
        catch(ParserException $e) {
            echo "Parser error. " . $e->getMessage() . ' Line ' . $e->line . PHP_EOL; 
        }
    }

    function emitVer($ver) {
        echo sprintf("id %s version date %s\n", $ver[2], $ver[3]);
        $this->ver = ['id' => $ver[2], 'date' => $ver[3]]; // remember the version 
    }
    function emitTrans($trans) {
        echo sprintf("Trans ver-id = %s serial = %s value = %s date = %s\n", $this->ver['id'], $trans[1], $trans[2], $trans[3], $trans[4]);
    }

    function outr($x) {
        print_r($x);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

$p = new Parser;
$p->parse('#VER 1 5 20170128
{
#TRANS 8000 {} 4016.00 20170128 "something"
#TRANS 1100 {} -4016.00 20170128 "something"
}
#VER 1 6 20170128
{
#TRANS 8010 {} 5016.00 20170128 "something else"
#TRANS 1130 {} -5016.00 20170128 "something else"
}');
```